# How to logout my application when I closed the window?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my chat application i am having the logout button and it works fine.

Now I need to logout the application when I closed the browser window also..How can I achieve this...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your logout code to the on [onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) event.

```
window.onunload = function () {
    //logout code here...
}
```

In JQuery you can use the [.unload()](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) function. Remember that you don't have much time so you may send the Ajax request but the result may not reach the client.

Another trick is to open a small new window and handle the logout there.

```
window.open("logout url","log out","height=10,width=10,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no",true);
```

If you want to disable closing the window (or at least warn the user), you can use this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    //if you return anything but null, it will warn the user.
    //optionally you can return a string which most browsers show to the user as the warning message.
    return true;
}
```

Another trick is to keep pinging the client every few seconds. If no reply comes back, assume the user has closed the window, browser has crashed or there is a network issue that ended the chat session anyway. On the client side, if you don't receive this ping package, you can assume that network connection or server has a problem and you can show the logout warning (and optionally let the user login again).

Comment: BUT it is impossible to call the server and guarantee to make it to the server.

Comment: then you can open a small popup window to take care of it or use window.onbeforeunload event handler to warn the user.

Comment: pop up window will be blocked by a pop up blocker, plus it still misses all the edge cases.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are using the popup window, you can do the logout process in that page behind the scene while warning the user. Then close the window when the logout is done. Maybe this goes so quick that the user will not even see the warning message :)

Comment: WATCHOUT: same is executed on page-reload ( F5 ) which you for sure dont want to log your out. For those who dont want to open a popup nor want to use XHR request, there are other possibilities: point either <image/>, <script/> or <iframe/> tag to the logout URL.

Comment: But what if there are multiple tabs open and you don't want to logout when 1 tab is closed?

Answer (score 14):

There is no exact way to do this with the clientside. There is no event that is fired when the page is exited. It should be done with the Session End event on the server.

You can try to use onbeforeunload or unload, but race conditions will prevent that from happening. AND they do not fire for browsers crashing, lost internet connection, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I dealt with this issue recently in my angularJS app - The main issue was that I don't want to log you out if you refresh, but I do want to if you close the tab.. Ajax requests with onbeforeunload/onunload aren't guaranteed to wait for response, so here is my solution:

I set a sessionStorage cookie on login that is just a bool - set to true when I get login response

`sessionStorage.setItem('activeSession', 'true');`

Obviously, on logout, we set this flag to false

Either when controller initializes or using window.onload (in my app.js file) - I check for this activeSession bool.. if it is false, I have this small if statement - where if conditions are met I call my logout method **ONLOAD** instead of onunload

```
   var activeSession = sessionStorage.activeSession;
    if (sessionStorage.loggedOutOnAuth) {
        console.log('Logged out due to expiry already')
    }
    else if (!activeSession) {
        sessionStorage.loggedOutOnAuth = true;
        _logout()
    }
```

Basically, the "loggedOutAuth" bool let's me know that I just expired you on page load due to the absence of an activeSession in sessionStorage so you don't get stuck in a loop

This was a great solution for me since I didn't want to implement a heartbeat/websocket

Comment: Did you find any issues sofar with this solution?

Comment: did you still use `onbeforeunload ` , `unload` to set the sessionsStorage variable to false ?

Comment: Good workaround! How do you handle a rememberMe option in that case? Would add the activeSession in the localStorage with a timestamp with the same scope as rememberMe keeps a token valid?

Comment: but how make that value false on browser is closed ?

Comment: I did implemented this solutions it works fine for single tab but if i tried to open app in new tab then there sessionStorage not available and use have to login again.

Comment: This may help on multiple tab open issues [https://blog.guya.net/2015/06/12/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-for-secure-multi-tab-authentication/]

Comment: Best solution, it save my day, Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Some websites are using the following script to detect whether window is closed or not.

```
if(window.screenTop > 10000)
alert("Window is closed");
else
alert("Window stillOpen");
```

You need to add the correct action instead of `alert()`

also take a look [HERE](http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2009/07/07/faqjavascript-user-confirmation-on-close-button-of-browser/) - I think this is somthing you need to detect the window closing

Answer (score 1):

I got the Solution by,

```
window.onunload = function () {
    //logout code here...
}
```

Thanks for all who supported me...

Comment: This should be posted as a comment

Comment: This solution will logout you also when you refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is some sort of "keepalive": the browser page "pings" the server with a small ajax request every minute or so.  If the server doesn't get the regular pings, the session is closed and can no longer be used.

As an optimization, the pings can be skipped if we have made another request to the server in the interim.

Advantages:

- still works with multiple windows open
- no problem with F5 / refresh
- can provides some usage statistics to the server

Disadvantages:

- when the window is closed, there is a delay before the user is logged out
- uses a little network bandwidth
- additional load on the server
- users might have concerns about the page constantly "phoning home"
- more difficult to implement

I've never actually done this in a web app, and not sure if I would; just putting it out there as an alternative. It seems like a good option for a chat app, where the server does need to know if you are still there.

Rather than polling / pinging, another possibility is to keep a "long running request" open while the page is open.  A chat app needs some such socket to receive new messages and notifications.  If the page is closed, the socket is closed too, and the server can notice that it has been closed.  It then waits a brief time for the client to establish a new socket, and if it doesn't we assume the page is closed and delete the session.  This would require some slightly unusual software on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was with this problem here and I come with a different solution:

```
    checkSessionTime();
    $interval(checkSessionTime, 2000);
    function checkSessionTime() {
        var now = (new Date()).getTime();
        if (!$localStorage.lastPing) {
            $localStorage.lastPing = now;
        }

        if ($localStorage.lastPing < now - 5000) {
            $localStorage.lastPing = undefined;
            AuthService.logout();
        } else {
            $localStorage.lastPing = now;
        }
    }
```

I like this solution cause it doesnt add overhead pinging the server nor rely on the window unload event. This code was put inside the `$app.run`.

I am using angular with a JWT auth, this way to me to log out just mean to get rid of the auth token. However, if you need to finish up the session server-side you can just build the Auth service to do one ping when finishing the session instead of keep pinging to maitain session alive.

This solutionsolves my case cause my intetion is just to prevent unwanted users to access someones account when they closed the tab and went away from the PC.

Comment: I need to logout the user if the tab is closed or refreshed. It should only do force logout on browser is closed.any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

After lots of search I wrote the below customized code in javascript and server side code for session kill in c#.

The  below code is extended in case of same website is open in multiple tabs so the session is alive till one tab of website is open

```
//Define global varible 
var isCloseWindow = false;

 //Jquery page load function to register the events

 $(function () {
        //function for onbeforeuload
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmLeave;
        //function for onload
        window.onload = ConfirmEnter;

        //mouseover for div which spans the whole browser client area 
        $("div").on('mouseover', (function () {
        //for postback from the page make isCloseWindow global varible to false
            isCloseWindow = false;
        }));
        //mouseout event
        $("div").on('mouseout', (function () {
     //for event raised from tabclose,browserclose etc. the page make isCloseWindow global varible to false
            isCloseWindow = true;
        }));
    });
     //Key board events to track  the  browser tab or browser closed by ctrl+w or alt+f4 key combination
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "CONTROL") {
            debugger;
            isCloseWindow = true;
        }
        else if (e.key.toUpperCase() == "ALT") {
            debugger;
            isCloseWindow = true;
        }
        else {
            debugger;
            isCloseWindow = false;
        }
    });

    function ConfirmEnter(event) {
        if (localStorage.getItem("IsPostBack") == null || localStorage.getItem("IsPostBack") == "N") {
            if (localStorage.getItem("tabCounter") == null || Number(localStorage.getItem("tabCounter")) == 0) {
                //cookie is not present
                localStorage.setItem('tabCounter', 1);

            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('tabCounter', Number(localStorage.getItem('tabCounter')) + 1);
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem("IsPostBack", "N");
    }
    function ConfirmLeave(event) {
        if (event.target.activeElement.innerText == "LOGOUT") {
            localStorage.setItem('tabCounter', 0);
            localStorage.setItem("IsPostBack", "N");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("IsPostBack", "Y");
        }
        if ((Number(localStorage.getItem('tabCounter')) == 1 && isCloseWindow == true)) {
            localStorage.setItem('tabCounter', 0);
            localStorage.setItem("IsPostBack", "N");
            **Call Web Method Kill_Session using jquery ajax call**
        } else if (Number(localStorage.getItem('tabCounter')) > 1 && isCloseWindow == true) {
            localStorage.setItem('tabCounter', Number(localStorage.getItem('tabCounter')) - 1);
        }
    }

 //C# server side WebMethod
 [WebMethod]
  public static void Kill_Session()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this issue I tried 2 solutions: *window.onbeforeunload* event and *sessionStorage*

- Since  *window.onbeforeunload* is not only for closing the browser but also redirect, tab refresh, new tab, it was not a robust solution. Also there are cases which the event does not happen: closing the browser through the command line, shutting down the computer
- I switched to using `sessionStorage`. When the user logs in I set a sessionStorage variable to 'true'; when the application is loaded I would check to see if this variable is there, otherwise I would force the user to log in. However I need to share the sessionStorage variable across tabs so that a user is not forced to log in when they open a new tab in the same browser instance, I was able to do this by leveraging the [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API); a great example of this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325763/browser-sessionstorage-share-between-tabs)

Answer (score 0):

```
tabOrBrowserStillAliveInterval;

constructor() {
  // system should logout if the browser or last opened tab was closed (in 15sec after closing)
  if (this.wasBrowserOrTabClosedAfterSignin()) {
    this.logOut();
  }

  // every 15sec update browserOrTabActiveTimestamp property with new timestamp
  this.setBrowserOrTabActiveTimestamp(new Date());
  this.tabOrBrowserStillAliveInterval = setInterval(() => {
    this.setBrowserOrTabActiveTimestamp(new Date());
  }, 15000);
}

signin() {
  // ...
  this.setBrowserOrTabActiveTimestamp(new Date());
}

setBrowserOrTabActiveTimestamp(timeStamp: Date) {
  localStorage.setItem(
    'browserOrTabActiveSessionTimestamp',
    `${timeStamp.getTime()}`
  );
}

wasBrowserOrTabClosedAfterSignin(): boolean {
  const value = localStorage.getItem('browserOrTabActiveSessionTimestamp');

  const lastTrackedTimeStampWhenAppWasAlive = value
    ? new Date(Number(value))
    : null;
  const currentTimestamp = new Date();
  const differenceInSec = moment(currentTimestamp).diff(
    moment(lastTrackedTimeStampWhenAppWasAlive),
    'seconds'
  );

  // if difference between current timestamp and last tracked timestamp when app was alive
  // is more than 15sec (if user close browser or all opened *your app* tabs more than 15sec ago)
  return !!lastTrackedTimeStampWhenAppWasAlive && differenceInSec > 15;
}
```

How it works:
If the user closes the browser or closes all opened *your app* tabs then after a 15sec timeout - logout will be triggered.

- it works with multiple windows open
- no additional load on the server
- no problem with F5 / refresh

Browser limitations are the reason why we need 15sec timeout before logout. Since browsers cannot distinguish such cases: browser close, close of a tab, and tab refresh. All these actions are considered by the browser as the same action. So 15sec timeout is like a workaround to catch only the browser close or close of all the opened *your app* tabs (and skip refresh/F5).

Answer (score 0):

I posted this originally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing/69950530#69950530) but I will repost here for continuity.

There have been updates to the browser to better tack the user when leaving the app. The event 'visibilitychange' lets you tack when a page is being hidden from another tab or being closed. You can track the document visibility state. The property document.visibilityState will return the current state. You will need to track the sign in and out but its closer to the goal.

This is supported by more newer browser but safari (as we know) never conforms to standards. You can use 'pageshow' and 'pagehide' to work in safari.

You can even use new API's like sendBeacon to send a one way request to the server when the tab is being closed and shouldn't expect a response.

I build a quick port of a class I use to track this. I had to remove some calls in the framework so it might be buggy however this should get you started.

```
export class UserLoginStatus
{
    /**
     * This will add the events and sign the user in.
     */
    constructor()
    {
        this.addEvents();
        this.signIn();
    }

    /**
     * This will check if the browser is safari. 
     * 
     * @returns {bool}
     */
    isSafari()
    {
        if(navigator && /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent))
        {
            return (/Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor) === false);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This will setup the events array by browser.
     * 
     * @returns {array}
     */
    setupEvents()
    {
        let events = [
            ['visibilitychange', document, () =>
            {
                if (document.visibilityState === 'visible')
                {
                    this.signIn();
                    return;
                }

                this.signOut();
            }]
        ];

        // we need to setup events for safari
        if(this.isSafari())
        {
            events.push(['pageshow', window, (e) =>
            {
                if(e.persisted === false)
                {
                    this.signIn();
                }
            }]);

            events.push(['pagehide', window, (e) =>
            {
                if(e.persisted === false)
                {
                    this.signOut();
                }
            }]);
        }

        return events;
    }

    /**
     * This will add the events.
     */
    addEvents()
    {
        let events = this.setupEvents();
        if(!events || events.length < 1)
        {
            return;
        }

        for(var i = 0, length = events.length; i < length; i++)
        {
            var event = events[i];
            if(!event)
            {
                continue;
            }

            event[1].addEventListener(event[0], event[3]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param {string} url 
     * @param {string} params 
     */
    async fetch(url, params)
    {
        await fetch(url, 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
        });
    }

    /**
     * This will sign in the user.
     */
    signIn()
    {
        // user is the app
        const url = '/auth/login';
        let params = 'userId=' + data.userId;

        this.fetch(url, params);
    }

    /**
     * This will sign out the user.
     */
    signOut()
    {
        // user is leaving the app

        const url = '/auth/logout';
        let params = 'userId=' + data.userId;

        if(!('sendBeacon' in window.navigator))
        {
            // normal ajax request here
            this.fetch(url, params);
            return;
        }

        // use a beacon for a more modern request the does not return a response
        navigator.sendBeacon(url, new URLSearchParams(params));
    }
}
```