# browser reload and close issue idea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I distinguish browser close and reload/refresh/f5 though jQuery/JS? I want to update database (via ajax) when close browser/tab and keep all as it is when reload.

What I am doing now is same action running when reload or close. But after reload again run a restore function (via ajax) to set back in previous state.

Tried [How can I detect browser tab refresh or close using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767136/how-can-i-detect-browser-tab-refresh-or-close-using-javascript) not worked. Any Idea? cron job is not real time. I need real time action

Professionals help please how you handle this issue.

Comment: the browser close can come form a lost of connection. then I see 2 possibility, first you save everything every 1 minute e.g.. secondly you save only what is changed by the user.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, this is not possible with JS - `onunload()` and `onbeforeunload()` functions are called in any page change event, regardless of where it came from... and they are the only one we can use to detect this

Comment: Cron job isn't realtime, but maybe you could run some cleanup procedure in the beginning of every php script related to that database stuff?

Comment: i think it's not possible