# Logout on tab closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger logout when I close any tab of my application. I tried
`$(window).on('unload', logout);` and `$(window).on('onbeforeunload', logout);` That works fine but events also triggered when I reload page. How can I prevent this on reload? Before asking I found some options like `event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type` but no posibility to separate reload and close in this way. Is there any opputurnity to trigger logout only on tab closed?

Comment: What "upload"?  I doubt there's any reliable way to do this.  The browser is under no obligation to notify the server that the user is closing anything.

Comment: f5 or browser upload button

Comment: *Re*load, then?

Comment: yes, on reload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66314375/5729064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per here [Is there a way in javascript to detect if the unload event is caused via a refresh, the back button, or closing the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291553/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-detect-if-the-unload-event-is-caused-via-a-refre) there is no way to detect the difference. Even if you could there would be other circumstances where it wouldn't work.